# Is there a way to return a child* to a base* and evaluate which child* has been returned?

Tags: c++, oop, class, pointers, inheritance

I tried this which didn't work:

```
void Map::OnLMClick(short xPos, short yPos)
{
    SObject* pSObject = pEditWindow->GetSelectedItem();

    if (pSObject==SOTile)
    {
       /* Do */
```

I tried this as a test:

```
SObject* EditorWindow::GetSelectedItem()
{
    return pSOTile[1]; //pSOTile[1] is a valid pointer, member of EditorWindow
}
```

SOTile class is a child of base class SObject. So, is it possible to create a Base* to get one of its child's* returned and then have the program react differently depending of what child it returned? If it is the case, how do I then have access to members of it's child that are not members of base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your types are polymorphic (i.e. if they have at least one virtual function), you can use `dynamic_cast`:

```
Base* pObject = get_object(); // May return a pointer to Derived
Derived* pDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pObject);
```

Notice, that dynamic downcasts are sometimes an indicator of bad design. Try to think if a better arrangement of virtual functions in your hierarchy would help.

Without knowing the concrete application domain, it is not possible for me to give more concrete advices.

Comment: I am creating a map editor. At some points, I'll want, by clicking on the map, to change a tile for another. At other times, I'll want to raise or lower height, or add objects on my tiles. SObjects are selectable objects that are selected before clicking on the map. If the SObject actually is a SOTile, clicking on the map won't do the same thing as if the SObject is, say, a decoration to add on a tile.

So, with these informations, can and would you help me more?

Comment: Forget it, I just found a solution. It was much simplier than I thought after all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: OK, sorry I was not fast enough to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[dynamic_cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) performs a special checking when a class is polymorhic.

```
   SOTile* pSOTile = dynamic_cast<SOTile*>(pSObject);
   if (pSOTile)
   {
      /* Do */
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `SOTile` is a pointer to a type that derives from `SObject`, you should not need to cast at all, since the compiler should be able to automatically resolve an `SObject` pointer from the derived pointer and then compare the two `SObject` pointers together (the same way that you can assign a derived pointer to a base pointer without type-casting).  Some compilers, like Borland's, support that just fine, eg:

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

Derived *d = ...;
Base *b = ...;

if (b == d) // <-- compiles fine
```

However, if for whatever reason your compiler does not allow that, you can manually cast the derived pointer using `static_cast` (don't use `dynamic_cast` to cast the base pointer):

```
if (pSObject == static_cast<SObject*>(SOTile))
```

If `SOTile` is not a pointer to a type that derives from `SObject`, `static_cast` will fail at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use dynamic_cast. Instead, you can implement that different behavior in different child class. Sometimes called as "[template metho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)d" pattern